# remove notch of dipchip from circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

I'd like to remove the notch / dot symbol of an IC drawn as `dipchip` with circuitikz (the notch is the semi-circualr symbol on top of the IC, see image attached). Is there a way to achieve this ?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,convert={density=600,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (0,0) node[dipchip, num pins=8, external pins width=0] (C) {IC};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use the key `no topmark` (manual around page 148)

Comment: indeed, I think we wrote at the same time :-) Thanks !

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are there dip chips that don't mark the pin 1 end of the chip?

Comment: not sure to understand the question... I just wanted to add another pin (Vcc)  where the notch is located. Although not physically there, conceptually it greatly improves the clarity of the schematic

Comment: @JohnKormylo I do not understand the question either... ;-)

Comment: The top mark serves an important role.  In addition to providing for human visual identification of the orientation of the package, the notch allows automated chip-insertion machinery to confirm correct orientation of the chip by mechanical sensing.  A dip without a notch just seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I missed the `no topmark` option to the node...

Comment: Can you accept your own answer (maybe removing the "stupid me" thing :-))) so that it will be marked solved? Thanks!